# How to I get bean value from bean.xml

Tags: java, spring, activemq-classic, apache-camel

we are tying to write 3 consumers for consuming messages from `Activemq` queue name as `ThermalMap` using `Apache Camel and Spring`.

I am new to `Spring`,I tried to get specific beanId("amqLinkId") value from `bean.xml`.For this I written the following 3 files.

VariablesDeclarations.java

```
public class VariablesDeclarations {
private String amqLink;
public String getAmqLink() {
return amqLink;
}
public void setAmqLink(String amqLink) {
this.amqLink = amqLink;
}
}
```

FirstConsumer.java

```
import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
public class FirstConsumer {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
     ApplicationContext contextObject=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("bean.xml");
        //Forwarding cursor to ConsumersMiddileWare class using CamelContext
        CamelContext camelObject=contextObject.getBean("activeContext", CamelContext.class);
        System.out.println("H");
}
}
```

ConsumersMiddileware.java

```
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
public class ConsumersMiddileWare extends RouteBuilder{
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Bye");
    BeanFactory beanFactory=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[]{"bean.xml"});
    VariablesDeclarations vd=(VariablesDeclarations) beanFactory.getBean("amqLinkId");
    System.out.println(vd.getAmqLink());
}
 }
```

bean.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                    http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd
                    http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core-5.5.0.xsd
                    ">

<!-- Creating camelContext element for forwarding to another ConsumersMiddileware class -->
<camelContext id="activeContext" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <routeBuilder ref="consumerMiddileWareContext" />
</camelContext>
<bean id="consumerMiddileWareContext" class="ActivemqPackage.ConsumersMiddileWare"></bean>

<!-- Following bean created for getting variable values into classes-->
<bean id="amqLinkId" class="ActivemqPackage.VariablesDeclarations">
    <property name="amqLink" value="activemq:queue:ThermalMap"></property>
</bean>
</beans>
```

WorkFlow :

If you run `FirstConsumer.java`,it should forward to `ConsumersMiddileWare.java`.There I want to find `amqLinkId` value from `bean.xml` and assign to any `String` object.

If I found `amqLinkId` value, later directly I Want to write the following code in `ConsumersMiddileWare.java`

```
  String activeMqURI=vd.getAmqLink();
  from( activeMqURI).to("bean:activemqProcessor?method=processMessage");
```

Problems:

If I trigger `FirsrConsumer.java`,it's forwading to `ConsumersMiddileWare.java`.It's keep on printing `Bye` not printing `amqLinkId` value like in the following way.

```
 Bye
 Bye
 Bye
 Bye
 .
 .
```

can anyone explain clearly.

Thanks

Comment: what is variables declaration class? Are the setters in place

Comment: yes,I will put that class defination also.

Comment: @Pratik I added `VaribaleDeclaration.java` class code and also added 2 more lines at the last.can you check it once.

Comment: Did u try by using ApplicationContext instead of BeanFactory in ConsumersMiddileware.java

Comment: @Pratik I tried,still I am facing same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a SpringRouteBuilder you can use instead of RouteBuilder. This class has some extra methods to get beans from the spring application context (eg the spring xml file)

```
public class ConsumersMiddileWare extends SpringRouteBuilder{
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    VariablesDeclarations vd = lookup("amqLinkId", VariablesDeclarations.class)' 
 }
```

And alternative is just to use the camelContext.getRegistry in the regular RouteBuilder

```
public class ConsumersMiddileWare extends RouteBuilder{
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    VariablesDeclarations vd = context().getRegistry().lookup("amqLinkId", VariablesDeclarations.class)' 
 }
```

Comment: Thank you, it's working fine.But I am getting the following error.`org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'activemqURL' defined in class path resource [bean.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/jms/ConnectionFactory`.

Comment: I have one more doubt, Instead of writing `amqLink` manually in `ConsumerMiddileware.java` can I pass `amqLink` from `FirstConsumer.java` to `ConsumerMiddileware.java` while forwarding time.

Comment: The NoClassDefFoundError indicates you need to add the JAR which has this class to your classpath.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your project is not able to find the  slf4j-simple-1.6.2.jar. Check if you have it in our project build path. If not add it and then check. Also the actual issue which you reported and the one you edited later are completely different issues.

Comment: I added `slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar` file.so I first 3 lines(What I put as a probelm in my question) are not coming. Still I am getting `Bye` continuously.How can I fix this.